# Il trolley o la trolley?

Tags: gender

Discussione in ufficio: si dice "*il* trolley" o "*la* trolley"?

Secondo me "*la* trolley" suona malissimo ma qualche collega ribatte che, come per "*la* fashion week" o "*una* start-up", si dovrebbe usare l'articolo femminile perché "trolley=valigia con le ruote".

Comment: Hai mai sentito dire “la trolley”? Penso che il riferimento italiano sia bagaglio in questo caso, spesso bagaglio a mano.

Comment: @Gio No, ma un mio collega dice di sì...

Comment: Ma va..ti prende in giro. Oppure fornisca evidenza di quello che dice.

Comment: @Gio Ottima idea, riferisco :)

Comment: Guarda anche qui: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+trolley%2Cla+trolley&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20trolley%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Gio Direi che "_la_ trolley" è inesistente ahahah

Comment: Secondo il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trolley) è "usato in ital. al masch.".

Comment: @Charo Grazie, se vuoi puoi anche scrivere una risposta :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il vocabolo "trolley" si trova nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trolley):

> ***trolley*** ‹*tròli*› s. ingl. [prob. dal v. (*to*) *troll* «muoversi (ruotando)», accorciamento dell’originario *trolley-pole* (con pole «asta, antenna»)] (pl. *trolleys* ‹*tròli∫*›), usato in ital. al masch. (talora, in passato, nel primo sign., adattato in *tròlle*).

L'indicazione «usato in ital. al masch.» ci fa vedere che, secondo questo dizionario, in italiano si usa «il trolley» e non «la trolley».

Answer (score 5):

La parola *trolley* è entrata in italiano ben prima che inventassero le valigie con le rotelle.

Indicava, come in inglese del resto, il palo con in cima una rotella che si agganciava alla linea aerea per il tram (e poi per il filobus), abbreviazione di *trolley-pole*.

[image]

[Fonte](http://moblog.net/view/175652/trolley-of-the-day-1700-sydney-australia-tram)

Come tale, è passato in italiano al maschile e così rimane anche per indicare una valigia.

Comment: Sei un pozzo di scienza!